# How to write custom detector for find sec bug plugin?

Tags: findbugs, spotbugs, find-sec-bugs

How to write custom detector for find sec bug plugin ? It will be help full if someone write a sample detector to detect the use of a word.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! please share what you have tried also. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have written a custom detector for finding the use of system.out.println. But it is giving lots of false positive. such as it's showing bug at the below statement  for (UploadForm object : uploadFormObj.getAllObjInExcel()).

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample code for detecting system.out.printl but it is showing lots of false positive bugs

```java
  package com.h3xstream.findsecbugs;

import org.apache.bcel.Constants;

import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.BugInstance;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.BugReporter;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.Priorities;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.bcel.OpcodeStackDetector;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.ClassDescriptor;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.FieldDescriptor;

public class CallToSystemOutPrintlnDetector2 extends OpcodeStackDetector {

    private BugReporter bugReporter;

    public CallToSystemOutPrintlnDetector2(BugReporter bugReporter) {
        super();
        this.bugReporter = bugReporter;

    }

    public void sawOpcode(int seen) {
        if (seen == Constants.GETSTATIC) {
            try {
                FieldDescriptor operand = getFieldDescriptorOperand();
                ClassDescriptor classDescriptor = operand.getClassDescriptor();
                if ("java/lang/System".equals(classDescriptor.getClassName())
                        && ("err".equals(operand.getName()) || "out"
                                .equals(operand.getName()))) {

                    bugReporter
                            .reportBug(new BugInstance(this,
                                    "MY_CALL_TO_SYSTEM_OUT_BUG",
                                    Priorities.NORMAL_PRIORITY)
                                    //
                                    .addClass(this).addMethod(this)
                                    .addSourceLine(this));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }

}
```